# how to change an existing variable to a global variable inside of an if condition

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I'm trying to make a little choose your own adventure game for fun and can't find a way to make this work. I want to be able to have a consistent pick up method where a specific action adds one to a variable and unlocks lines of dialogue under other actions. What I've got right now is something like this.

```
item = 0
while True:
   act = input()
   if "action" in act:
      if(item != 1):
         print("You don't have that item.")
         continue
      else:
         print("You use the item.")
         continue
   if "take item" in act:
      print("You take the item.")
      global item
      item = item + 1
      continue
```

The issue I'm finding is that when I try to set the global variable, the program claims a syntax warning:

```
main.py:107: SyntaxWarning: name 'item' is assigned to before global declaration global item
```

since the variable is stated before the global, but if I don't state the variable before hand, the system I have in place to prevent the wrong dialogue from printing won't work. How do I have a conditional global variable that updates an existing local variable?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what precisely isn't working with your code? Are you aware that the line `"You use the item."` has no effect? It appears that you're missing a call to `print`. Also note that using the `global` keyword isn't necessary if you're already in the global scope.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I edited the post to further elaborate my issue.

Comment: Please include the full text of the syntax error in your question.

Comment: Right. It's a warning upon further reading, but it still doesn't update the value despite me setting it to global and going through the if function.

Comment: Is this your complete code, or is it taken from the body of a function? If its from a function, then the assignment `item = 0` binds to a _local_ variable, not a global variable.

Comment: It's not the complete code, just a chunk I removed from the problem area. Even if it is a local variable, trying to change it to a global variable is doing nothing, whether is it inside or outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

You don't need the `global` keyword. Remove that line and your code will work.

### Short Explanation

In Python, everything is "global" (not accurate, I will explain in long explanation) so you rarely need to use the `global` keyword. You can try the following code in the interactive Python REPL:

```py
>>> def test(y):
...     return x, y
... 
>>> test(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> x = 4
>>> test(3)
(4, 3)
```

Here, I'm using a function as an example, if and while/for loops are exactly the same.

I'm declaring a function called `test` that takes in a parameter `y`, but it will return the tuple `(x, y)`. Here, `x` is undefined. You would expect that it returns an error, but it actually doesn't until you run it.

When we run `test(3)`, Python will complain that `x` is not defined so it cannot run the function. However, if we define `x = 4` even after our function declaration, the function will work. Hence `test(3)` will return `(4, 3)`. Here, `x` is treated as a global variable.

### Long Explanation

```py
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> def test2():
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
...     return x, y
... 
>>> test2()
(1, 2)
>>> x
3
>>> y
4
>>>
```

Notice that y is not touched, even though it's clearly being assigned a different value in the function `test2`.

How is this possible? Actually, Python functions technically do have a scope of their own, and changes to function variables are isolated and do not change the variables of the same name outside the function. Loops and if statements don't have their own scope, so the variables inside if statements are the exact variables outside them.

```py
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> if True:
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
... 
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

When you reference a variable in functions, Python will check if a value is assigned to a variable of that name in that function (either as a parameter or inside the function block). If there is a variable with that name, Python will use the variable in the function (within the scope of the function). If not, Python will try to look for a function that's in the scope outside (either another function or the global scope). If Python searched till the global scope and there is no variable of that name, it will finally produce an error.

```py
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> def function1():
...     x = 4 # this x is being used
...     def function2():
...             print(x)
...     function2()
... 
>>> function1()
4
>>> def test3():
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
...     return (x, y)
... 
>>> test3()
(1, 2)
>>> x
3
>>> y
4
```

This means, only when you are trying to change the value of a variable outside of the current scope, you will use the `global` keyword. However, this is BAD PRACTICE. Whenever you find yourself doing this, you need to think about whether you should refactor your code to using classes. It's a very bad practice to change the value of global variables inside functions no matter the language you are using.

```py
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> def test4():
...     global x, y # refers to the global x and y
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
...     return (x, y)
... 
>>> test4()
(1, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```